# SpringBoot RabbitMQ - how to reduce boilerplate for many topics (events)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I wonder if there is a way to reduce amount of boilerplate code when initializing many RabbitMQ queues/bindings in SpringBoot?

Following event-driven approach, my app produces like 50 types of events (it will be split into several smaller apps later, but still).
Each event goes to exchange with type "topic".
Some events are getting consumed by other apps, some events additionally consumed by the same app which is sending them.

Lets consider that publishing-and-self-consuming case.

In SpringBoot for **each event** I need to declare:

1. routing key name in config (like "event.item.purchased")
2. queue name to consume that event inside the same app
   ("queue.event.item.purchased")
3. matching configuration properties class field or a variable itemPurchasedRoutingKey or constant in code which keeps property name (like ${event.item.purchased})
4. bean for Queue creation (with a name featuring event name) like
   itemPurchasedQueue
5. bean for Binding creation (with a name featuring
   event name) and routing key name. like itemPurchasedBinding which is
   constructed with itemPurchasedQueue.bind(...itemPurchasedRoutingKey)
6. RabbitListener for event, with annotation containing queue name
   (can't be defined in runtime)

So - 6 places where "item purchased" is mentioned in one or another form.
The amount of boilerplate code is just killing me :)
If there are 50 events, its very easy to make a mistake - when adding new event, you need to remember to add it to 6 places.

Ideally, for each event I'd like to:

1. specify routing key in config. Queue name can be built upon it by appending common prefix (specific to the app).
2. use some annotation or alternative RabbitListener which automatically declares queue (by routing key + prefix), binds to it, and listens to events.

Is there a way to optimize it?
I thought about custom annotations, but RabbitListener doesn't like dynamic queue names, and spring boot can't find beans for queues and bindings if I declare them inside some util method.
Maybe there is a way to declare all that stuff in code, but it's not a Spring way, I believe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using manual bean declaration and using 1 bind() method for each bean

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(RabbitProperties::class)
class RabbitConfiguration(
    private val properties: RabbitProperties,
    private val connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory
) {

    @Bean
    fun admin() = RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory)

    @Bean
    fun exchange() = TopicExchange(properties.template.exchange)

    @Bean
    fun rabbitMessageConverter() = Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(
        jacksonObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
            .registerModule(Jdk8Module())
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL)
    )

    @Value("\${okko.rabbit.queue-prefix}")
    lateinit var queuePrefix: String

    fun <T> bind(routingKey: String, listener: (T) -> Mono<Void>): SimpleMessageListenerContainer {
        val queueName = "$queuePrefix.$routingKey"
        val queue = Queue(queueName)
        admin().declareQueue(queue)
        admin().declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange()).with(routingKey)!!)

        val container = SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory)
        container.addQueueNames(queueName)
        container.setMessageListener(MessageListenerAdapter(MessageHandler(listener), rabbitMessageConverter()))
        return container
    }

    internal class MessageHandler<T>(private val listener: (T) -> Mono<Void>) {

        // NOTE: don't change name of this method, rabbit needs it
        fun handleMessage(message: T) {
            listener.invoke(message).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()).subscribe()
        }
    }
}


@Service
@Configuration
class EventConsumerRabbit(
    private val config: RabbitConfiguration,
    private val routingKeys: RabbitEventRoutingKeyConfig
) {

    @Bean
    fun event1() = handle(routingKeys.event1)

    @Bean
    fun event2() = handle(routingKeys.event2)

    ...

    private fun<T> handle(routingKey: String): Mono<Void> = config.bind<T>(routingKey) {
        log.debug("consume rabbit event: $it")
        ... // handle event, return Mono<Void>
    }

    companion object {
        private val log by logger()
    }
}

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("my.rabbit.routing-key.event")
class RabbitEventRoutingKeyConfig {
    lateinit var event1: String
    lateinit var event2: String
    ...
}
```